# Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated ON xampp\htdocs\SMS-CI\os\core

Tags: php, uri

SMS Debug ===> Error Encountered!
Severity: 8192

Message: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 73

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->config =& load_class('Config', 'core');
    log_message('debug', "URI Class Initialized");
}
```